# How can i get number of miliseconds sine unix epoch from my timestamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

From backend i get the following time stamp - which is UTC

For example:

```
let dateTimestamp = '2021-05-06T22:00Z';
```

To get the miliseconds i used

```
 let miliseconds = moment.utc( dateTimestamp).valueOf();
```

and that gives me this result `1620338400000`

but the miliseconds i get are based on my localtime not on UTC

for example the local time for this date is `2020-12-26T00:00Z`.

To check that i used

```
 var dateString = moment.unix(miliseconds /1000).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A')
```

and that gives me this result `Friday, May 7th, 2021 12:00:00 AM`

i need to get unix miliseconds from this timestamp `2021-05-06T22:00Z` in UTC.

I also tried

```
moment( dateTimestamp).valueOf();
```

but still i get miliseconds until my localtime not on the UTC timestamp i provided in moment

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

> but the miliseconds i get are based on my localtime not on UTC

No, they aren't. :-) Milliseconds-since-The-Epoch values are **always** measuring the number of miliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 at mdnight UTC. It's just that your code to check is incorrect: `format` is using your local timezone to **format** what you see as a string, but that's just the format. The value specifies exactly what you want it to: The date/time you've shown, in UTC, as milliseconds since The Epoch.

To check, use

```
new Date(1620338400000).toISOString()
```

```js
console.log(
    new Date(1620338400000).toISOString()
);
```

or the moment equivalent

```
moment.utc(1620338400000).format()
```

```js
console.log(
    moment.utc(1620338400000).format()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```